# When does a hypercover imply hyperdescent?

Tags: sheaf-theory, simplicial-stuff

Suppose we have a site $\mathcal{C}$ and $S$ is an object of $\mathcal{C}$. Let $F$ be a sheaf of abelian groups on $\mathcal{C}$ and let $S_\bullet$ be a simplicial hypercover of $S$.

My question is: when is the induced complex

$$0 \to F(S) \to F(S_1) \to F(S_2) \to  \dots$$

exact? (here the complex is taken to be the Moore complex of the induced cosimplicial abelian group, in the same way as Dold-Kan correspondence).

Is there an easy criterion for this?

It is not hard to show in the first case, since $F(S)$ is just the equaliser of the two maps $F(S_1) \to F(S_2)$, but I can't seem to prove it beyond that.

Would it help if $\mathcal{C}$ is the site of compact Hausdorff spaces with finite jointly surjective families of maps as covers

Comment: There seem to be some missing details. You say "induced simplicial abelian group" – well, yes, the hypercover gives you a simplicial abelian group, and the Moore complex of that is a chain complex, but you have written down a cochain complex. Did you apply Hom somewhere? You say that $F (S)$ is the equaliser of $F (S_1) \rightrightarrows F (S_2)$, as if $F (S_\bullet)$ is a cosimplicial object – but the objects in the Moore complex are different from the objects in the simplicial object.

Comment: @ZhenLin A sheaf is contravariant. The hypercover $S_\bullet$ is a simplicial object in $C$ and $F(S_\bullet)$ a cosimplicial abelian group.

Comment: @Roland Yes, I know how to fill in the details. I am not sure the OP does.

Comment: @ZhenLin Yes, I do know how to fill in the details. I mistyped and should have said cosimplicial abelian group. This cosimplicial group gives two maps $f,g: F(S_1) \to F(S_2)$. Hence, the map $F(S_1) \to F(S_2)$ in the Moore complex is $f-g$. The kernel of this is the same thing as the equaliser of the two maps.

Comment: @marlasca23 What kind of condition are you expecting ? I mean, an hypercover can be used to compute the cohomology of $F$ (if the hypercover is "good" or if you take the colimit over all the hypercover). So $F$ should be acyclic and the hypercover "good".

Comment: @marlasca23 It seems the question in the title is different from the question in the body. The definition of hyperdescent does not require the whole cochain complex to be exact. If you use the standard definition of hyperdescent then any sheaf of abelian groups automatically has hyperdescent. But you could also consider a sheaf of abelian groups to be a sheaf of chain complexes concentrated in degree 0 and in that case hyperdescent would be something different but, I think, still not the same as what you wrote down.